# Kafka Stream API vs Consumer API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I need to read from a specific Kafka topic, do a VERY short processing on the message and pass it on to a *different* Kafka cluster.

Currently, I'm using a consumer that's also a producer on the other kafka server.

However, the streaming API supposedly offers a more light-weight high-throughput option.

So the questions are:

- Assuming my processing code doesn't require much horse power, is the streaming API better?
- Does the streaming APi support writing to a different Kafka cluster?
- What are the Streaming API cons comparing to the Consumer API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately KafkaStreams doesn't currently support writing to a different Kafka cluster.

Comment: As a work around, you could use `#process()` and use an extra `KafkaProducer` instance there. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796207/dynamically-connecting-a-kafka-input-stream-to-multiple-output-streams