# Kafka Streams dynamic routing (ProducerInterceptor might be a solution?)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working with Apache Kafka and I've been experimenting with the Kafka Streams functionality.
What I'm trying to achieve is very simple, at least in words and it can be achieved easily with the regular plain Consumer/Producer approach:

1. Read a from a dynamic list of topics
2. Do some processing on the message
3. Push the message to another topic which name is computed based on the message content

Initially I thought I could create a custom Sink or inject some kind of endpoint resolver in order to programmatically define the topic name for each single message, although ultimately couldn't find any way to do that.
So I dug into the code and found the *ProducerInterceptor* class that is (quoting from the [**JavaDoc**](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html)):

> A plugin interface that allows you to intercept (and possibly mutate)
>   the records received by the producer before they are published to the
>   Kafka cluster.

And it's *onSend* method:

> This is called from KafkaProducer.send(ProducerRecord) and
>   KafkaProducer.send(ProducerRecord, Callback) methods, before key and
>   value get serialized and partition is assigned (if partition is not
>   specified in ProducerRecord).

It seemed like the perfect solution for me as I can effectively return a new *ProducerRecord* with the topic name I want.
Although apparently there's a bug (I've opened an issue on their JIRA: [**KAFKA-4691**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4691)) and that method is called when the key and value have already been serialized.
Bummer as I don't think doing an additional deserialization at this point is acceptable.

My question to you more experienced and knowledgeable users would be your input and ideas and any kind of suggestions on how would be an efficient and elegant way of achieving it.

Thanks in advance for your help/comments/suggestions/ideas.

**Below are some code snippets of what I've tried:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamsConfig streamingConfig = new StreamsConfig(getProperties());

    StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();
    StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

    MyObjectSerializer myObjectSerializer = new MyObjectSerializer();

    TopologyBuilder topologyBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
    topologyBuilder.addSource("SOURCE", stringDeserializer, myObjectSerializer, Pattern.compile("input-.*"));

    .addProcessor("PROCESS", MyCustomProcessor::new, "SOURCE");


    System.out.println("Starting PurchaseProcessor Example");
    KafkaStreams streaming = new KafkaStreams(topologyBuilder, streamingConfig);
    streaming.start();
    System.out.println("Now started PurchaseProcessor Example");

}

private static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    .....
    .....
    props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG), "com.test.kafka.streams.OutputTopicRouterInterceptor");

    return props;
}
```

**OutputTopicRouterInterceptor onSend implementation:**

```java
@Override
public ProducerRecord<String, MyObject> onSend(ProducerRecord<String, MyObject> record) {
    MyObject obj = record.value();

    String topic = computeTopicName(obj);

    ProducerRecord<String, MyObject> newRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, MyObject>(topic, record.partition(), record.timestamp(), record.key(), obj);
    return newRecord;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically connecting a Kafka input stream to multiple output streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796207/dynamically-connecting-a-kafka-input-stream-to-multiple-output-streams)

Comment: Using an interception might work, too. Never thought about it -- but doing the deserialization-serialization step might be tricky and a performance penalty -- on the other hand, if you compare the answer of the other question, sync write are a performance penalty, too. Not sure which one is the better solution. The interception idea sounds a little hacky to me though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MatthiasJ.Sax. What do you think about the JIRA? Is it valid? I agree that the interceptor solution seems hacky although I also haven't found any good reason to rule it out, at least as a temporary solution, waiting for more support from Kafka on this end. Your feedback is appreciated

Comment: I comment on the JIRA.

Comment: The motivation to add producer and consumer Interceptors is just for measurement and monitoring,you can get more from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors#KIP-42:AddProducerandConsumerInterceptors-Motivation)

Comment: It is a bit late, but for those who are interested - kafka streams now has [Topology.addSink](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html#addSink-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopicNameExtractor-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer-java.lang.String...-) which allows routing to custom topics. [TopicNameExtractor](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/TopicNameExtractor.html) is used for this purpose