# Split Topic Data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I want to split a topic into serveral topics, based on specific fields in the data. Is there a possibility to do such operations in the streaming itself?

Or should I write a typically Consumer and Producer?

**Example**:

*Input Topic*: Data with attributes A (values AAA, BBB, CCC), B, C, D and E

*Output Topics*: 3 Topics with Name AAA, BBB and CCC with the same data as in Input Topic

Kind Regards,
Lukas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically connecting a Kafka input stream to multiple output streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796207/dynamically-connecting-a-kafka-input-stream-to-multiple-output-streams)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [branch() method](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#stateless-transformations) in your stream to split into several streams. Than each stream can write in own topic.

Comment: I want to split into several streams dynamically, so it’s not possible to use the branch method, because I should know the split criteria before. I have to split the incoming stream into hundreds of other streams. I think I can only use the consumer and producer to do this.

Comment: Hi Lukas, as far as i know streams, you could archive such behavior only using own consumers-producers pair. Also, have a look at low-lvl api of streams, may be in sink processor you can define needed functionality.