# Does KStream process one message at a time?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka streaming and i have a doubt.

My code is

```
final KStream<String, Entity> inStream = builder.stream(TOPIC);
inStream.map((key, entity) -> {
    ....
    return new KeyValue<>(key, entity);
}).to(NEW_TOPIC);`
```

Value of `NEW_TOPIC` is present in entity object. My problem is how to i extract the value of this `NEW_TOPIC` from entity in case of multiple task running.

My problems drill down to the fact that if there are multiple task, would kafka-streaming process the incoming message till end (by calling the to() method to push it back to new kafka topic) and then pull new message from incoming topic? If this is the behavior, i can store this value in a local /final variable to use it later. If this is not the behavior then i need to use some other way.

Comment: yes, depending on the type of entity object, there would be different topics. This info would be part of entity.

Comment: Not possible , read https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4936

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41799272/10722561  you can create a producer and produce message put it may be slow.

Comment: @Himeshgoswami the link you shared is for different issue. As i understand, that is for extracting topic details within the payload, in my case i am specifically providing which topic it has to go.

Comment: Could you describe how you do _"in my case i am specifically providing which topic it has to go."_?

Comment: org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopicNameExtractor solved my problem.