# How do you send the record matching certain condition/s to specific/multiple output topics in Spring apache-kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

[I have referred this. but, this is an old post so i'm looking for a better solution if any.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796207/dynamically-connecting-a-kafka-input-stream-to-multiple-output-streams?rq=1)

I have an input topic that contains 'userActivity' data. Now I wish to gather different analytics based on userInterest, userSubscribedGroup, userChoice, etc... produced to distinct output topics from the same Kafka-streams-application.

Could you help me achieve this... ps: This my first time using Kafka-streams so I'm unaware of any other alternatives.

**edit:**

It's possible that One record matches multiple criteria, in which case the same record should go into those output topics as well.

```
if(record1 matches criteria1) then... output to topic1;
if(record1 matches criteria2) then ... output to topic2;
and so on.
note: i'm not looking elseIf kind of solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically choosing which topic to send to at runtime based on each record's key-value pairs. Apache Kafka version 2.0 or later introduced a feature called: [**Dynamic routing**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-303%3A+Add+Dynamic+Routing+in+Streams+Sink)

And this is an example of it: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/dynamic-output-topic/confluent.html

Comment: okay thank you, I understand that with this approach One record can go into one of the output topics. The same record cannot go into multiple topics. Am I right?

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way to send the same record into multiple topics if it matches certain criteria.

Comment: I've edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Your use-case, actually, for each `if(recordX matches criteriaN) then... output to topicN;` I will create **a KStream instance** with `.filter` is the condition filter in IF clause and `.to(topicN)`.